# Customize PATH variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for an answer to my questions but I can not find it.

I have an outside environment in the Windows environment (external partition ...). I have specific environment variables that are defined at launch of the command prompt. This cmd allows me to execute the commands :

- npm
- grunt
- bower
- ...

I installed a standalone version of VSCode (external partition) and I wish it to run automated Grunt tasks with the `Ctrl+Shift+P` > `Run Task` > `My Task`
So, I create a tasks.json to integrate it in VSCode but when I want to execute them, I have the following error:

```
'Node' is not recognized as an internal control
or external, program or batch file.
```

On the cmd, environment path are correctly configured and working perfectly with my Grunt tasks. But in VSCode, no tasks work.

**Are there any way to configure all my environment path (node, grunt...) for VSCode without installing them on my pc?**

Here an exemple of my `tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "${cwd}\\node_modules\\.bin\\grunt",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "isWatching": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Show help",
            "args": [
                "help"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you define the variables when `cmd.exe` starts, the environment variables are only visible in that `cmd.exe` session. To see the variables in all new processes, set them from the control panel.

Comment: But if I set in the control panel, my independent partitions are useless. It's impossible to configure them with a setting or something like that in VSCode ?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside environment" and "independent partition"?

Comment: It's an independent VHD partition

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goals, but you can run a shell script (`.cmd` or `.bat` file) that launches `code.exe`, but before doing so, sets the environment variables you want.